# jquery issues when posting parameters to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

I'm basically trying to pass parameters from a table full of editable divs and trying to save them on a database

My table code and script are here http://jsfiddle.net/j8f5vm1u/5/

This is part of my main file products.php where I display all the products stored in the products table be them active or not(for sale or not)

```
<table id="tablapro">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>weight(Kg)</th>
        <th colspan="3">Dimensions(LXAnXAl)</th>//L stands for lenght, An for width, Al for Height 
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Activt</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div id="n3">Lámpara 3</div></td><td><div id="pr3">18.00</div></td><td><div id="pe3">0.8</div></td><td><div id="l3">20</div></td><td><div id="an3">20</div></td><td><div id="al3">20</div></td><td><div id="e3">9</div></td><td><div id="a3">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="3">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n4">Lámpara 4</div></td><td><div id="pr4">22.00</div></td><td><div id="pe4">1.1</div></td><td><div id="l4">20</div></td><td><div id="an4">20</div></td><td><div id="al4">20</div></td><td><div id="e4">16</div></td><td><div id="a4">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="4">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n5">Lámpara 5</div></td><td><div id="pr5">23.00</div></td><td><div id="pe5">1.2</div></td><td><div id="l5">20</div></td><td><div id="an5">20</div></td><td><div id="al5">20</div></td><td><div id="e5">24</div></td><td><div id="a5">Si</div></td><td><button class="save" value="5">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n6">Lámpara 6</div></td><td><div id="pr6">15.00</div></td><td><div id="pe6">0.9</div></td><td><div id="l6">20</div></td><td><div id="an6">20</div></td><td><div id="al6">20</div></td><td><div id="e6">16</div></td><td><div id="a6">Si</div></td><td><button class="save" value="6">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n7">Lámpara 7</div></td><td><div id="pr7">19.00</div></td><td><div id="pe7">1.1</div></td><td><div id="l7">20</div></td><td><div id="an7">20</div></td><td><div id="al7">20</div></td><td><div id="e7">34</div></td><td><div id="a7">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="7">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n8">Lámpara 8</div></td><td><div id="pr8">21.00</div></td><td><div id="pe8">1.2</div></td><td><div id="l8">20</div></td><td><div id="an8">20</div></td><td><div id="al8">20</div></td><td><div id="e8">12</div></td><td><div id="a8">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="8">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n9">Lámpara 9</div></td><td><div id="pr9">28.00</div></td><td><div id="pe9">1.1</div></td><td><div id="l9">20</div></td><td><div id="an9">20</div></td><td><div id="al9">20</div></td><td><div id="e9">18</div></td><td><div id="a9">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="9">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n15">Lampara 1</div></td><td><div id="pr15">19.50</div></td><td><div id="pe15">1.1</div></td><td><div id="l15">19</div></td><td><div id="an15">15</div></td><td><div id="al15">15</div></td><td><div id="e15">100</div></td><td><div id="a15">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="15">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n16">Lámpara 2</div></td><td><div id="pr16">27.80</div></td><td><div id="pe16">1.7</div></td><td><div id="l16">17</div></td><td><div id="an16">18</div></td><td><div id="al16">19</div></td><td><div id="e16">100</div></td><td><div id="a16">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="16">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="n17">Lámpara 10</div></td><td><div id="pr17">24.00</div></td><td><div id="pe17">1.8</div></td><td><div id="l17">21</div></td><td><div id="an17">13</div></td><td><div id="al17">15</div></td><td><div id="e17">50</div></td><td><div id="a17">No</div></td><td><button class="save" value="17">Guardar</button></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my main js file estilos.js

```
$(document).ready(function () { into inputs
$("#tablapro div").click(divClicked);
});//i use this function to turn all the divs elements into inputs and also insert the ids

function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = $(this).html();
    valorid = $(this).attr("id");
    var aText = $('<input id="' + $(this).attr("id") + '" type="text" />');
    aText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).replaceWith(aText);
    aText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    aText.blur(aTextBlurred);
    }//this changes the divs to inputs and allows the insertion of text

function aTextBlurred() {
   var ahtml = $(this).val();
   var aText = $('<div id="' + valorid + '" />');
   aText.html(ahtml);
   $(this).replaceWith(aText);
   // setup the click event for this new div
   aText.click(divClicked);
   }//this changes the inputs back to normal and changes its content to store the changes

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".save").click(saveid);
});// this function allows me to retrieve the content of the elements using its ids

function saveid(){
    var divid=$(this).val();//this is the product's id
    var nomrow=$('#n'+ $(this).val()).html();//the product's name 
    var prerow=$('#pr'+$(this).val()).html();//the product's price 
    var perow=$('#pe'+$(this).val()).html();//the product's weight
    var lonrow=$('#l'+$(this).val()).html();//the product's box length 
    var anrow=$('#an'+$(this).val()).html();//the product's box width
    var alrow=$('#al'+$(this).val()).html();//the product's box height
    var exrow=$('#e'+$(this).val()).html();//the product's units
    if($('#a'+$(this).val()).html()=="Si"){
    var acrow=1;
        }
    else{
        var acrow=0;
    };//whether the product will display or not on the main page

    alert(divid + " "+nomrow + " " + prerow + " " + perow + " " + lonrow + " " + anrow + " " + alrow + " " + exrow + " " + acrow );
//to check if its catching the right values

    var postData={
        "id" : divid,
        "nomp" : nomrow,
        "prep" : prerow,
        "pep" : perow,
        "lonp" : lonrow,
        "anp" : anrow,
        "alp" : alrow,
        "exp" : exrow,
        "acp" : acrow
        };//formatting the data for the $.post

    $.post( 'salva.php',
           postData,function(data,status){
    console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
           });//salva.php is the destination file for the previous values
}//in there I will update the products table with the new values


<?php 
/*include_once "../php/config.php";
$nombre=$_POST['nomp'];
$precio=$_POST['prep'];
$peso=$_POST['pep'];
$largo=$_POST['lonp'];
$ancho=$_POST['anp'];
$altura=$_POST['alp'];
$existencias=$_POST['exp'];
$activo=$_POST['acp'];*/
$data = array('success' => 'Register Completed', 'postData' => $_REQUEST);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Well it seems to work fine because when I check at the log I get the following.

POST http://www.storetest.xxx/salva.php

Data: {"success":"Register Completed","postData":{"id":"3","nomp":"L\u00e1mpara 3","prep":"18.00","pep":"0.8","lonp":"20","anp":"20","alp":"20","exp":"9","acp":"0","PHPSESSID":"9c2135f2d6fa5a43f5ebf3a166942296"}}
Status: success

When I try to assign the values to any of the commented variables in salva.php they come out as null.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. Unless you think the PHP is the issue...

Comment: Have you `var_dump`'d the `$_POST` array? What do you get?

Comment: Btw the Data: {"success":"Register Completed","postData":{"id":"3","nomp":"L\u00e1mpara 3","prep":"18.00","pep":"0.8","lonp":"20","anp":"20","alp":"20","exp":"9","acp":"0","PHPSESSID":"9c2135f2d6fa5a43f5ebf3a166942296"}} Status: success is the comment that i get in the browsers console